# Как повернуть текст (TextBlock) в DockPanel?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

Конечно же так:

```
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="test text test text" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </DockPanel>
```

скажут многие. Попробуйте сделать это и посмотрите что не так. У меня, например, *рект* блока с текстом становится очень странным (что видно в конструкторе). На манипуляции с *DockPanel.Dock* блок никак не реагирует.

Мне нужно, чтобы текст был прижат к левому или правому краю (*DockPanel.Dock*) и следовал сверху вниз или снизу вверх (*RotateTransform Angle="+-90"*) на мой выбор. Но я не могу этого сделать. Попробуйте и убедитесь (

Уточнения:

- Версия студии 2015 Enterprise, версия Framework .Net 4.0
- Проверил на студии 2013, 4.5 FW - то же самое!

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится.

Comment: @Discord Пришлите скриншот, что у вас получилось с кодом xaml пожалуйста. И я добавил уточнения в вопрос.

Comment: @Discord, проверил на другой машине и на другой студии с другим фреймворком. Проблема воспроизводится. Проблема не в том, что текст не поворачивается. Читайте вопрос внимательно.

Comment: Учитывая, что проблема у вас, то и скриншот с вас. Информации в вопросе — ноль. "Рект блока очень странный" — что угодно, но не информация. У меня: http://i.imgur.com/we9GWJV.png

Comment: Код: `<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"><DockPanel Background="DodgerBlue"><TextBlock Text="test text test text" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="2" Background="LightBlue"><TextBlock.LayoutTransform><RotateTransform Angle="-90"/></TextBlock.LayoutTransform></TextBlock><Border Background="LightSkyBlue"/></DockPanel></Window>`

Comment: @Discord, В примере не было      <Border Background="LightSkyBlue"/> . Это, как раз, решение.

Comment: Где решение? Я просто все контролы раскрасил, чтобы было видно, что где разместилось.

Comment: @Discord, Не в раскраске дело. Текстовый элемент растянулся по ширине панели, но я этого не видел. Вместо этого в конструкторе я видел рект текстового блока, уходящий за пределы окна, что и сбило меня с толку. Уберите минус, зачем он мне? )

Comment: Минус за отсутствие скриншота и внятного описания проблемы. И то, что вы называете "конструктором", обычно называют "дизайнером".

Comment: @Discord, В данном случае я не знал, как описать понятнее. Понятно бы стало после копипаста кода из моего примера )  А конструктором я его называю, потому что в локализованной студии он называется "конструктор"

Comment: А вот и последствия локализации... Ох... Вообще, я думал, что локализованной версией никто не пользуется.

Comment: @Discord, если уж придираться, то Designer в данном контексте - именно конструктор. А дизайнером его называли изначально по невежеству, теперь по привычке. :) Мне нравится родной язык, что в этом плохого? Я бы и переменные называл по-русски, если бы коллеги на меня за это не матерились ))

Comment: Это обычный беспощадный и бессмысленный профессиональный сленг, к нему нет смысла предъявлять претензии, когда он уже сложился. Собственно, вся проблема локализаций в том, что они придумывают свои термины, с которыми привыкшие к сленгу незнакомы.

Comment: @Discord, я и не осуждаю сленг. Он упрощает общение в разных кругах, вот только знать же надо не только слово, но и его определение, а значит тот, кто использует сленг должен понимать и литературное обозначение (базовое название). Если я скажу "материнская плата" вместо "мать", специалисты же меня поймут, не так ли? Так же и тут, вопрос я задаю специалистам, но воспользуются информацией потом обычные смертные :)

Comment: Есть нормальные термины, а есть разброд и шатание при локализации софта. Например, я всё время путаюсь, что такое перекрытие, переопределение, перегрузка методов и далее по списку — я тексты на русском практически не читаю, поэтому в голове каша. И это ещё нормальные термины! А если посмотреть всякие dependency property — пиши пропало. В MSDN они называются "свойства зависимостей", например. Я решительно отказываюсь запоминать эту билиберду, потому что я не могу произнести её всерьёз.

Comment: @Discord, Мелкософтные продукты, как правило, качественно локализованы. По поводу Dependency соглашусь. Тут было бы корректнее "зависимое свойство". А уж если и такое определение вам не нравится, то не должно нравится и само "Dependency Property", потому что этот термин - криво сжатая не информативная суть того, что он из себя представляет. Перекрытие, переопределение и перегрузка - тоже не информативные термины, как и их оригинальные названия на английском. Просто вы отложили у себя в голове некие операции, привязали к ним английские термины и выучили это наизусть.

Comment: @Discord, в русском языке больше слов, больше свободы и, как результат, больше способов описания. Читать его (точнее смысл, заложенный в предложениях) намного сложнее. Английский же язык более.... декларативный, что ли. На нем проще объяснять, не боясь, что тебя поймут как-то иначе. Поэтому он и является международным.   Документацию на русском читать приятнее, на мой взгляд, когда перевод качественный. То же касается локализации программ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Последний контрол в `DockPanel` по умолчанию заполняет всё свободное пространство. Соответственно, у вас могли возникнуть проблемы из-за того, что блок текста растянулся, если блок текста последний контрол в панели. Чтобы отключить это поведение, задайте у `DockPanel` свойство `LastChildFill="False"`.